# Django web application Taking user input and processing it

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am building a web application using django. I need to take a string input from the user and process it using a method I have written myself. How to achieve this in Django? Here are the things I need to do

1. Get User Input `userinput = (string)` On start page
2. Put this string as an argument in my method `MyMethod(userinput)` and Run it in the backend
3. Display what `MyMethod()` returns on another page.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not code-writing service, so please show your effort for people to be willing to help you. Start from reading [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/), in particular section about [writing simple forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial04/#write-a-simple-form).

Comment: I am sorry for I cant really share the code due.Till now I have seen the tutorials, I know how to create forms and store whatever is inputted into the db that django creates. I don't need a code from this service, I just need some indiactions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that you start from django tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Basically, what you are going to need is form with one text field, HTML template that will render the form, view that will render HTML template with instance of a form when GET request arrives and call your MyMethod with value from form when POST request arrives and URL rule to call your view function on some URL.

Without additional data or any attempt to solve it and concrete problem you encounter - I can hardly offer more help.

Comment: Thanks @del-boy . This is exactly what i was looking for. A hint as to how to get the input to the view file. I called the POST method and sent the command to a particular URL that I defined which in turn sent the stuff to my VIEW function for processing it, and a TEMPLATE displayed what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `model` with fields which you want to update by user input, then create a `form` based on this model. Then import this in a `view` and render it in a `template`

simple example:
forms.py:

```
class InputForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['fields_from_YourModel']
```

views.py:

```
from .forms import InputForm

def user_input(request):
    input = CustomUser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    if request.POST:
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=input)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
    else:
        form = ProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'input.html', {'form':form})
```

Other steps more easier for beginner, you'll find examples in docs